# Yii2 create theme options page in backed like Wordpress?

Tags: php, yii2

i am new in Yii2 Framework. right now i used yii2 advanced framework with Frontend and Backend. Now client want theme options page like Wordpress. i couldn't find any help from Google. please give me suggestion how can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Questions like this don't belong on SO. However i am more concerned your doing a project for a client and don't know the solution to something as simple as this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer your question. I think by theme options you are asking to save some settings value for a project, which admin will be able to change. If I am right, then I used to do this as follows

Create a simple table as wp_options table. And save the data in the options table with meta key and meta value style. And to save the value or read
I use active record. You can get [help](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html) from this page about saving multiple settings value. And while fetching you can use SiteSettings::find(['meta_key'=>'Your Condition or meta Key name']) .

Hope this will help you.